# Can you provide us an example of an infinite product of functions in the Pólya class that belongs to this class?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product, entire-functions, hadamard-product

Please, see in this Wikipedia's article the definition and examples of [Pólya class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_class). After I tried work easy questions I was asking myself if

> **Question.** Can you to create an example of an infinite product of functions $E_n(s)$ that belong to (in) the Pólya class, and this infinite product $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty E_n(s)$$ also belongs to the Pólya class?
>
> If is required that you work with the conditions that the factors of you infinite product have no roots on $\Im z>0$ I accept it (I am saying this because I don't understand well the theory, thus if you need this condition you can take it).

This is I would like to know if make sense such example, where does converge your infinite product?

Many thanks.

Comment: I am asking about the more easy example that one can to create. Is it possible show with an example that an infinite product belongs in Pólya class? Thanks.

Comment: is $1$ in the Polya class ?

Comment: You are welcome @mercio, many thanks for your attention. Yes, it is an example, thus an infinite product of $1's$ is an example.